# Different events for CheckBox's box and label?(JavaFX)

Tags: checkbox, javafx

I want my `CheckBox` to become selected only when box is clicked. If `CheckBox`'s label is clicked I want to perform different action with this `CheckBox` being not selected. How is it possible to achieve this?

[image]

I made separate checkbox and label. But I can't change label's pseudo class through checkbox. They are al in listview. Here is a part of the code:

```
HBox todoHBox=new HBox(0);
CheckBox todoCheckBox=new CheckBox();
Label todoLabel=new Label(item.getName());
Label timeLabel=new Label();
Region rSpring = new Region(); 
todoHBox.setPrefWidth(300);
todoHBox.setHgrow(rSpring, Priority.ALWAYS);
todoHBox.setHgrow(timeLabel, Priority.ALWAYS);
todoHBox.setHgrow(todoCheckBox, Priority.NEVER);
timeLabel.setMinWidth(60);
timeLabel.getStyleClass().add("time-label");
todoLabel.getStyleClass().add("todo-label");
todoHBox.getChildren().addAll(todoCheckBox,todoLabel,rSpring,timeLabel);
todoHBox.setMargin(timeLabel, new Insets(3,0,0,0));
PseudoClass pseudo = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("task-done");
todoCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(e->{
if(todoCheckBox.isSelected()){
       todoLabel.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudo, true);
       }else{
             todoLabel.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudo, false);
              }});
             setGraphic(todoHBox);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two controls: a `CheckBox` with no text and a `Label`. Call `setOnMouseClicked(...)` on the `Label` with a handler that does whatever you need.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckBoxWithLabelExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> 
            System.out.println("Check box is now "+(wasSelected ? "not ":"") + "selected"));
        Label label = new Label("Make Task");
        label.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Text clicked"));
        HBox control = new HBox(checkBox, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(control), 350, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't figure why I can't change label's appearance through checkbox(edited question, added code).